# StyleCop spelling breaks TeamCity

Tags: stylecop, teamcity-7.0

I just upgraded StyleCop from 4.7.36.0 to 4.7.37.0 (the latter now includes spelling support).
It works fine on my local machine.

However, when it runs in TeamCity (where it worked before) I now get:

```
        Violations
         Line 1   An exception occurred while parsing the file: 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception, %1 is not a valid 
    Win32 application at StyleCop.Spelling.SpellChecker.Speller..ctor(String path)
```

It seems to be looking for a spelling program. Perhaps some windows feature should be activated on the build server. But what?

Comment: I have the same problem on our tfs build server.  http://stylecop.codeplex.com/discussions/395792

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in StyleCop 4.7.38.0.